# Difference between grep -l and find in UNIX

Tags: unix, find, grep

Is there a difference between grep -l and find in UNIX?

Answer (score 16):

`grep -l` prints file names where the **file contents** contains the pattern

`find` prints file names where the **file name** contains the pattern

Answer (score 4):

`grep` is used to look for a pattern in data (either from file or from standard input).
`find` is used to look for a filename in filesystem.